# Tutorial page in portuguese

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following some tutorials and got to this page in portuguese (?). Is this an error in the websites language handling system?

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingPublisherSubscriber

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350902/tutorial-page-in-portuguese/) by [argentum2f](https://answers.ros.org/users/54112/argentum2f/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-04-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-29**:
This is essentially a duplicate of #q350120. But another instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for reporting. Someone edited the default page instead of the PT_BR page.
I have reverted the change and it should be good now.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2020-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0